# Pass dynamic variables in options to Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to pass a Series number in a Google Chart option through a variable. However it is not accepting it as a variable and instead is taking it as a string. You can see in Image1 that I have passed in Series parameter SecondseriesColumnNumber as a variable and value is 1.

Image 1
[image: Image 1]

However in the output it is considering it as a string but not as the series number as shown below

Image 2

[image]

Other parameters are considering the values correctly but not the series one. How can I make this work? My code is below

```
var options = {
    title: title,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
    chartArea: { left: "8%", right: "8%", top: "10%", width: "100%", height: "75%" },
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    tooltip: { textStyle: { color: 'black' }, isHtml: true },
    isStacked: isStacked,
    seriesType: seriesType,
    series: { SecondseriesColumnNumber: { type: SecondseriesType } },
    hAxis: { slantedText: true }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart($('DivSeries')[0]);
```

Comment: Please post all your codes in the question itself. Codes in external links or images is not allowed in SO.

Comment: I have posted my code in the question itself, can't you guys see that? It's just the debug information that I have posted as screenshot. It's ridiculous that it has been marked as off-topic.

Comment: I have voted to re-open this.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewL. Don't understand the logic of the mods, a clear question with the error screenshot and code included in code blocks, still getting flagged

Comment: I honestly think you should include more code other than the `options` variable though. Like how the html looks like especially the `DivSeries` element you're targeting.

Comment: My problem is only in the options part of code, hence I have added only that. However, since you suggest to add the output, I will add it as well.

Comment: @Hitesh Just a comment about the moderation : it's (most of the time) community based. If someone flags the question or someone with enough reputation vote to close, then it goes to a queue. This queue is quite big (~8k questions), and people can choose to leave open or vote to close up to 40 questions. In my experience, most of the time the question will end up closed, even if it "doesn't deserve it" or if it gets corrected lately. That's because I think people go very quickly in that queue and often don't pay enough attention, most of the time the question indeed is off-topic.

Comment: To also take the side of the other members that have voted to close, I'd like to stress AndrewL's last comment to add some target html and the needed code to reproduce your problem easily when starting from scratch, for instance add the `<script>` tag importing the google-vizualisation lib that you use. That would help your question to have a clear [mcve] (see https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Good news on this moderation system is that, since someone has voted to reopen the question, it is now in another queue (much smaller) I voted to reopen.

Comment: (just so you know, currently there are 3 votes to reopen and 2 to leave closed)

Comment: So you see, without making a single edit to the question, it was pretty much clear and answered correctly as well. That's what my point was. Peace !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem has to do with JavaScript syntax.
you are not able to use a variable as a key in the definition of an object.
you must first create the object, then you can add additional keys using variables.

there are two ways to get / set values of object keys, once the object is defined.
both of the following will return the same value for title.

```
var title = options.title;
var title = options['title'];
```

where as in the latter, we can substitute a variable for the title key.

```
var key = 'title';
var title = options[key];
```

in this case, define the static options as needed.

```
var options = {
    title: title,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
    chartArea: { left: "8%", right: "8%", top: "10%", width: "100%", height: "75%" },
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    tooltip: { textStyle: { color: 'black' }, isHtml: true },
    isStacked: isStacked,
    seriesType: seriesType,
    series: {},
    hAxis: { slantedText: true }
};
```

then you can use a variable to further define the series option.

```
var SecondseriesColumnNumber = 1;
options.series[SecondseriesColumnNumber] = { type: SecondseriesType };
```